# O365 Excel issue with plotting data

Tags: microsoft-excel

this is my first post to this forum after getting much help from answered questions over the years. I have a setup where an Arduino board is gathering temperature data every second. In the future I will have a MATLAB program grab the data and automatically save and plot it, however the couple tests I have run so far must be used. To get the data in Excel I simply copied and pasted the data from the Arduino monitor onto the sheet.

The problem after this is that the data contains a time stamp and other identifying information i.e. Thermocouple A/B. I have found a simple command to grab the last N number of characters of the cell with =right(cell, # of characters), but these numbers do not plot correctly. The x-axis (time) is correct as I just entered integers starting from one, but the y-axis is not formatted correctly. I tried reformatting the cells from 'general' to 'number', however this has no effect. Thank you for your time.

Sample Data:

```
A                                               B   C   D
11:07:34.103 -> Thermocouple B Temp(C): 18.91       1   18.91 
11:07:35.356 -> Thermocouple A Temp(C): 17.86       2   17.86 
11:07:35.636 -> Thermocouple B Temp(C): 18.99       3   18.99 
11:07:36.887 -> Thermocouple A Temp(C): 17.92       4   17.92 
11:07:37.119 -> Thermocouple B Temp(C): 18.99       5   18.99 
11:07:38.372 -> Thermocouple A Temp(C): 17.92       6   17.92 
11:07:38.604 -> Thermocouple B Temp(C): 18.97       7   18.97
```

Here is a screenshot of how it currently plots the data (grabbing six characters).
[Incorrect Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxxFl.png)

Here is another screenshot of it plotting with five characters.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hsDA.png)

So I took Bruce's advice and used the column splitting wizard to separate the time and temperature and after sorting out the unneeded thermocouple A values I plotted the temperature versus time successfully.

Comment: Instead of posting a link to the workbook, can you copy/paste some data here (format as table with the code tags, `{}`)? Or at worst, a screenshot?  I (and likely others) are wary of opening random files from online.

Comment: Sorry about that Bruce, I understand your hesitation. Here is a portion of the data. {11:07:34.103 -> Thermocouple B Temp(C): 18.91      1  18.91
11:07:35.356 -> Thermocouple A Temp(C): 17.86      2  17.86
11:07:35.636 -> Thermocouple B Temp(C): 18.99      3  18.99
11:07:36.887 -> Thermocouple A Temp(C): 17.92      4  17.92
11:07:37.119 -> Thermocouple B Temp(C): 18.99      5  18.99
11:07:38.372 -> Thermocouple A Temp(C): 17.92      6  17.92
11:07:38.604 -> Thermocouple B Temp(C): 18.97      7  18.97
} I'm not sure if I used the brackets correctly.

Comment: Stack Exchange generated this link after I tried uploading the table. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQMaF.png Sorry if you have to type in manually.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited your OP.  What is the expected output?  What numbers are you trying to format correctly?

Comment: Thank you for the formatting help. I'm trying to just plot the numbers in the C column for the x-axis and the numbers in the D column for the y-axis for a temperature over time graph. Also, only thermocouple B needs to be plotted. I'm just seeing that numbers in the D column that were grabbed from A using the function do not plot correctly.

Comment: It may help to see a screenshot of the graph where the Y Axis isn't plotting correctly.  Also, what formula are you using exactly to get column D?  `=RIGHT(A1,5)` should pull just those five characters...

Comment: I posted one just now. Also, further down the data has a temperature of over 100 so that is why I chose six characters. Reducing down to five still gives an incorrect plot.

Comment: Try using `=RIGHT(A1,5)`, since you're pulling `6` characters, it's including an extra space which could be throwing off the plot.

Comment: I just uploaded another screenshot of it pulling five characters. It still does the same thing.

Comment: Odd! If I manually type the data in, I get a correctly working chart. Even using `TEXT([formula],"00.00")` I get the chart you do...one minute let me see...

Comment: @PaulCantrelle, when you use a text function, like RIGHT, to extract the number, it produces a text string with characters that happen to be numbers.  If you use TEXT to format numerical information, that result is also text.  If you use a chart that's looking for numerical information, it won't use text.  In that case, you need to do something that gets Excel to treat the numbers as numbers.  A lot of things will do that, like using the result in an arithmetic operation.  (cont'd)

Comment: Certain operations, like Text to Columns, if what it extracts could be a number (even though it's text in the original cell), it will assume it's a number and store it that way.  But you need some kind of step that gets the text to be treated as a number before you try to use it in the graph if the graph is looking for a numerical value.

Comment: That is good to know, @fixer1234. If in the future I have to do a lot more charts for this work I'll try and use the way you said to format the information. As I mentioned in my post, though, I'll be using MATLAB to process the information for the remaining tests that haven't been completed. I'll only have to use the workaround for another two workbooks thankfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, using a formula (`=RIGHT(TRIM(A1,5))`), I can't get the chart to work correctly.

However, and this might help with other things too, if I send the text to columns (Data Tab, "Text to Columns"), you get numbers that *do* work:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the video showing me. I'll have to try and replicate this.

Comment: I successfully used the splitting wizard and got the plot working. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @PaulCantrelle - Glad it's working!  You can mark this as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post (below the up/down arrows)

Comment: Something that might be easier to automate is wrapping the function in _value()_, like so: =VALUE(RIGHT(TRIM(A1),5)).  That should convert a numeric string into an actual number.  You may need to make sure the cell is formatted to a numeric type, as well.

Comment: @kbelder mind putting that as an Answer? IMO the above is a workaround to the actual question, which your comment (and fixer1234's above) seems to actually solve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer kbelder. That makes sense.